# Matplotlib suptitle printed over old suptitle

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib 1.2.1 in ubuntu 13.10 64bit

I have a function that creates and saves a plot and I am calling that function several times. However in some cases the suptitle is drawned over the old one, making a mess.
I think this is related to the following question, but I didn't manage to understand the reply in that question:
[Matplotlib suptitle prints over old title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559144/matplotlib-suptitle-prints-over-old-title)

My code is as follow:

```
# =======================================================================
def plotMultivariable(scenarios_h, variables_h, region, title, filename):

  nvar = len(variables_h)
  nscen = len(scenarios_h)
  plt.figure(1)
  maintitle = unicode(title, 'utf_8')
  plt.suptitle(maintitle, fontsize=16, ha='center')
  for i in range(nvar):    
    plt.subplot(nvar,1,i)
    title = unicode(variables[variables_h[i]][0], 'utf_8')
    ylabel = unicode(variables[variables_h[i]][1], 'utf_8')
    plt.title(title)
    plt.ylabel(ylabel)
    for scenario in scenarios_h:
      for spGroup in spAggregates.keys():
        serieName = unicode(spGroup + " - " + scenario, 'utf_8')
        serieColor = scenarios[scenario]
        serieLineType = spAggregates[spGroup][2]
        serieWidth = spAggregates[spGroup][3]
        key = region, variables_h[i], scenario, spGroup
        y = odata[key]
        plt.plot(x, y, serieLineType, label=serieName, linewidth=serieWidth, color=serieColor)
  plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.6)
  plt.savefig(chartoutdir+"/"+filename)
  #plt.show()
```

And I call this function with:

```
plotMultivariable(['reference','vRegEnd075','vRegFixed','vRegFromHr'],['expReturns','vReg','vol','hV'],'11000','Management effect','management.png')
plotMultivariable(['reference','withRisk06','withRisk08','withRisk10'],['expReturns','vReg','vol','hV'],'11000','Risk effect','risk.png')
plotMultivariable(['nonspatial','reference','withVariance'],['expReturns','vReg','vol','hV'],'11000','Spatial explicit simulations','space.png')
```

Here are the resulting plots. If I view them instead of saving they are fine. Any hint or help with understandingh the reply in the cited answer? Thank you..

[image: first image (ok)]
[image: second plot (ok)]
[image: third plot (title overdrawn)]

Comment: By the way, you could improve the look of your labels using LaTeX formating, replacing `"Mm^3"` by `r"Mm$^3$"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should close your figure in the end to clear properly everything; just add

```
plt.close()
```

in the end of your function and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, what may disturbs you is that `matplotlib` is state-aware (I don't know the exact word) and keeps track in the background of already-created objects [even if this is a bug, as explained in the linked question]. Closing the plot, as answered by MBR, should solve your problem.

Another way, as explained by the question you link, would be to keep reference of the created suptitles. Then, as they behave as `Text` objects, you can change their characteristics, notably the text displayed.