# How to flush away the default suptitle of boxplot with subplots made by pandas package for python

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, boxplot, subplot

In the following example, I try to make boxplots of "Emission" vs "Voltage" for four "Power" levels, with each power level occupying a subplot.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,9))
i = 0
for Power in [10, 20, 40, 60]:
    i = i+1
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2,2,i)
    subdf = df[df.Power==Power]
    bp = subdf.boxplot(column='Emission', by='Voltage', ax=ax)
fig.suptitle('My Own Title')
```

The problem is that the

```
fig.suptitle('My Own Title')
```

command doesn't flush away the default "Grouped by Voltage" suptitle. What am I missing here? Or is it a bug?

Thanks.

Comment: perhaps the title is tied to the axes, not the figure. try `ax.set_title`.

Comment: I've got 4 axes in this figure, shouldn't the suptitle belong to the figure instead of an axes?

Comment: Seems reasonable. But I can't run your example without your dataframe, so it's hard to know exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are generated by `suptitle()` calls, and the super titles are the children of `fig` object (and yes, the `suptitle()` were called 4 times, one from each subplot).

To fix it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Emission': np.random.random(12),
                   'Voltage': np.random.random(12),
                   'Power': np.repeat([10,20,40,60],3)})
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,9))
i = 0
for Power in [10, 20, 40, 60]:
    i = i+1
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2,2,i)
    subdf = df[df.Power==Power]
    bp = subdf.boxplot(column='Emission', by='Voltage', ax=ax)
fig.texts = [] #flush the old super titles
plt.suptitle('Some title')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. "fig.texts" is also explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559144/matplotlib-suptitle-prints-over-old-title

Comment: The only problem is, when you have 4 subplots like this case, `fig.texts` contains 4 `matplotlib.Text.text` objects (`pandas` 0.14.1), it might be a better idea to clean up that first...

Answer (score 5):

You can also do this without manually creating a figure first:

```
ax = df.boxplot(by=["some_column"])
ax.get_figure().suptitle("")
```

Answer (score 0):

Until someone can give a better answer, here is a hack, assuming the new title is longer than the old one.

```
fig.suptitle('My Own Title',backgroundcolor='white', color='black')
```

It basically hides the old title, instead of flushing it.